# C# Quizz , Object private/public

Tags: c#, object, double, private, public

So i have this code:

```
class TimePeriod
{
    private double seconds;

    public double Hours
    {
        get { return seconds / 3600; }
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    }
}
```

My quizz demand is : Using the code below, create an object with associated property. Display a message with it in the console.

I'm not sure what it wants. (i just need the code , not the whole program) .
I know how to use Console.Write but the first part of the demand i don't really understand. Thank you in advance

Comment: Demanding to write code for you is really bad accepted here. Especially if you haven't shown any effort to solve your problem

Comment: I have almost zero knowledge of C# ... i'm trying to resolve a quizz for me and my colegues for an exam in 2 days. Time is not on my side... :(

Comment: It's a trick question! There is no code below the statement that says "Using the code below". Put that as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements didn't make sense to me for a while, either, but on reflection I believe they just want this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The quiz lasted {0} hours.", (new TimePeriod() { Hours = 2.0 }).Hours);
```

That creates an instance of the class they gave you, sets the property, and uses that instance and property value to show a message in the Console.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume they are asking you to create a new Time Period Object such as

```
    TimePeriod tp = new TimePeriod();
    tp.Hours = 12.00;
```